# examples from timeline-2.6.1 not working - error links is undefined timeline code 0

Tags: javascript, chap-links-library

Just started using Chaps links library - timeline, works fine if I copy any of the examples of Github and paste them in my `index.jsp` page, I have made sure that I reference the location of `timeline.js` and `timeline.css` correctly.

However, when I paste the code in a `jsp` page that gets launched as a result of a get request going through my controller, I get no timeline showing. The page error says "links is undefined". I am hardcoding the data an exact copy of the example demo so I am not feeding any data. Any idea how to resolve it?

EDIT - ok the problem is with the way I am trying to load Javascript library in Spring MVC. It has nothing to do with the timeline component.

Answer (score 0):

issue resolved. Added  in my dispatcher servlet followed by mvc:resource tag inputting mapping and location. mvc annotation was missing